# Assigning/returning an imported json file to a variable in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, cypress

I have a json file that contains data like this

```
{
  "login": {
    "email": "Email",
    "firstName": "First name",
    "lastName": "Last name",
    "noAccountYet": "No account yet?",
    "password": "Password",
    "signIn": "Sign in",
    "signInWithApple": "Sign in with Apple",
    "signInWithGoogle": "Sign in with Google"
  },
  "errors": {
    "invalidCredentials": "Invalid credentials",
    "invalidEmail": "Not a valid e-mail address"
  }
}
```

I want to import it into a `helper-functions` file and return the entire object from a `const` or `function` to be accessed with dot-notation, like this:

```
// helper-functions.ts
import * as en from '../../src/assets/i18n/en.json';
import * as de from '../../src/assets/i18n/de.json';

export const translationHandle: any = () => {
  if (Cypress.env('LANG') === 'en') {
    return en;
  } else {
    return de;
  }
};


// assigned in a different file
const lang = translationHandle();
// and accessed using dot-notation like  lang.errors.invalidEmail
```

I'm writing E2E tests with Cypress for a dual-lingual app. And I would like to have access to the correspondent language text file based on the language set in the global environment.

The problem is that the returned value from the `const translationHandle` above is `undefined`. Although, running in debug mode shows that `lang` itself contains a `Module`, it's only when I try to access it with dot-notation do I get a Cypress error that it's undefined.

I also tried to just do this locally in each file with `if-else` and assigning the correspondent language object to a `const`. However, I also get `undefined`.

The only that worked for me thus far is if I directly access the file as imported, e.g. `en.login.lastName`.

I am aware that this issue stems from my lack of understanding of how TypeScript works, and so I'm not only asking for answers to this specific issue, but also any resources/explanations that could help me clear my misunderstandings.

Comment: If you log `Cypress.env('LANG')` is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: Yes, it is as expected.

Comment: does `import en from '../../src/assets/i18n/en.json';
import de from '../../src/assets/i18n/de.json';` not work?

Comment: It works, but the problem is I need to only use one or the other, and it's determined based on the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with how I was importing the `.json` - not really a problem but I just wasn't aware of its functionality. I was doing `import * as en from ./file/name/` which was adding a `default` root field in the object. That's because `import *` [imports the namespace, which contains all the other exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_an_entire_modules_contents). Changing the import statement to `import en from` resolved the issue. Alternatively, I could've just added the default field name to the dot-notation sequence: `en.login.signUp` => `en.default.login.signUp`.